# (Android)Need to fire an event when user touches to the screen an another when releases?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to fire an event when user touches to screen an another(this is the part i stuck) when releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Touch listener, the MotionEvent will have an Action type of "ACTION_DOWN" when the user presses, "ACTION_UP" when he releases. See [the motion event documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).